# How can I create multi level lists [bullet points/numbers] in AEM RTE?

Tags: list, components, aem, rte

I want the content author to be able to write something like this using RTE.

1. First Item
2. Second Item

   - First Subitem
   - Second Subitem
3. Third Item
4. Fourth Item

When I try to use inden/outdent with bulletlist/numberlist features of Adobe CQ's RTE component, my created sample text looks like this:

1. First Item
2. Second Item

   - First Subitem
   - Second Subitem
3. Third Item
4. Fourth Item

How to make sure that the desired output is generated?

Comment: Please clarify your question, your actions, the expected behavior and the observed behavior.

Comment: Your two examples look identical to me. Am I missing something?